# Updating Constraints programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, size-classes

I need to **update a constraint** programmatically in my project to adjust a view's height accordingly (based on different subviews). I've made outlet of the constraint in my controller but facing an issue.

when I try to update this for the first time *(in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear* *method*), it's not updated. and if i update it afterwards (because of some rotation etc), then it is done correctly. **Kindly tell me why this is happening and what is the right way/place to do this?** (As i feel that the constraint is updated somewhere again after my updation in viewWillAppear/DidLoad).

I tried **view.layoutIfNeeded** as well but it didn't help. I guess it has something to do with viewDidLoad and other viewController delegate methods

P.S. I'm also using *size classes* in my project but I think it has nothing to do with that as it's working in some cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating constraints may not work in `viewWillAppear`.
It will, however, work in `viewDidAppear`.

There are other places you may overwrite, such as: (using `static BOOL shouldRefreshView = NO;` for the first time)

```swift
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    if(shouldRefreshView) {
        shouldRefreshView = NO;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Comment: Which option did you pick? `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: i picked "viewDidLayoutSubviews". I think it's more appropriate. + i didn't use that shouldRefreshView variable.. @SwiftArchitect